# Where is the shadow trinket?

Tags: swordigo

I know there is a shadow trinket that can be put on your armour to regain health. The only problem is that I do not know where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=QrwZ3Csj0Io#t=110) next time ;)
The Youtube video shows how to get the trinket at 1:50.

Basically:
If you're at the `Wellcliff Graveyard` get to the upper left and enter the `Corrupted Crypt`:
[image: The entrance of the crypt]

The trinket is on the right behind a wall, which unlocks as soon as you've defeated the enemys.

Hope this was what you where looking for.

Comment: Please include the necessary parts of the linked content here in case the link breaks or the content behind it changes. I would also like to discourage suggesting to google it, as this page is already #5 on the linked Google search.